# How can I tell a n channel MOS varactor from a p channel MOS varactor using the CV plot (gate-source capacitance on gate source voltage)?

Tags: varactor

1. I couldn't find the differences of the 2 types of varactors (varicaps). I used the CV method and got the curve, but I don't know if I have a n type or p type. How can you tell?
2. How do you calculate the capacitance curve with CV voltages?

Comment: Perhaps if you listed the part numbers here.  Varactors are a type of diode and they don't have "channels" like a MOSFET device.

Comment: The whole idea of the lab is that I shouldn't know, but see it in the graph. I don't want to cheat :)
I think it was a MOSFET used as varaktor, we did the CV method on it

Comment: Varactors are diodes, not FETs. There's only one type of them.

Comment: But doesn't a MOSFET have a capacitance like a varactor? I think we took a MOSFET and ran a sweep and took the gate source voltages and calculated the capacitance from them, I mean the code did that, so I'd like to know how.

Comment: It appears that there are varactors  made with MOSFET technology, and that there is a marked difference in their CV curves.  [Does this help?](http://www.mos-ak.org/grenoble/slides/04_Victory_MOS-AK.pdf)

Comment: It was a power transistor, but yea what are those differences?
I don't see a distinction between n and p types there

Comment: It's in the slide show.  There's a page with a couple of CV plots.  The P type has a real advantage over the N type.